# Help understanding Android permissions

Tags: permissions

I recently discovered there's a lot more to Android permissions than I originally thought. For example looking at the permissions for the Signal app, I've given it permissions that I would like to it have.

[image: Basic permissions]

But if you tap on All permissions, there appears to be a lot more this app can do that I originally thought.

[image: All permissions]

Is my understanding of this how it appears? For example it can "take pictures and videos" or "modify my contacts" - I don't want it modifying my contacts

Since I have Signal for privacy, this is very concerning. I've noticed similar things with (e.g.) Telegram. Have I understood this right?

Comment: The first screen shot shows the permission groups. The second shows what belongs to each group but those permissions can only be used if you have enabled the corresponding group.

Comment: If you want to view and control apps' permissions in a simple and comprehensive way, give [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) a try. Disclosure: I'm the author of the app.